# is "capturing moments for social media" correct?

Tags: prepositions, pronouns, reflexive-pronouns

I wrote:

> ...a considerable part of Americans admitted that they put the goal of capturing moments for social media before living the moments themselves.

is this correct or should I use "on" instead of "for"?

also, what does "themselves" refer to? Does it refer to "moments" or "Americans"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*On* is probably better than *for* - if you use *for* you're implying that they capture the moments to post later, whereas if you use *on*, you're suggesting that they are capturing them to post live.

*Themselves* could refer to either the people or the moments: I read it as referring to the people until your question made me consider the other possibility.

*A considerable part of Americans* is not idiomatic. *A (x) part of* is normally used only with definite terms. I would simply use *A considerable number of Americans*